# simple $watch on service doesn't work but can access service

Tags: angularjs

I'm picking up AngularJS and I'm running into an issue where I cannot seem to watch a variable, seems pretty straight forward but I can't figure out what is wrong.

**Service**

```
app.factory('pathModalService', function() {
var path;
return {
    getPath: function(){
        console.log('get path');
        return path;
    },
    setPath: function(newPath){
        console.log('set path:' + newPath);
            path = newPath;
    }
}
});
```

**Controller that sets**

```
app.controller('PathsCtrl', ['$scope', 'pathModalService', function($scope, pathModalService){
$scope.edit_path = function(){
    pathModalService.setPath('test1');
}
}]);
```

**Controller that is watching**

```
app.controller('PathModalCtrl', ['$rootScope', 'pathModalService', function($scope, pathModalService){
$scope.$watch(pathModalService.path, function() {
    console.log('Change to Path');
}, true);
$scope.test = function(){
    console.log(pathModalService.getPath());
}
}]);
```

The inclusion of the path modal service is working correctly as I can forcefully read it, but watching it does nothing except when the app first runs (weird).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7QbCG/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pathModalService.path` is undefined since `path` is a closure variable. You need to register the watch on `pathModalService.getPath`

```
$scope.$watch(pathModalService.getPath, function() {
    console.log('Change to Path');
}, true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xt2V/)

My Test o/p for [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xt2V/1/)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't trigger it still?

Comment: @DavidNguyen did you check the demo? when you click on `Test Set` in console `Change to Path ` is printed

Comment: @DavidNguyen what was the previous problem?

Comment: I believe it worked but I cleared console and setting it to the same variable didn't trigger the message :)

Comment: @DavidNguyen I thought so, that was why I changed to value to random in the set method